# Bloomberg bbcomm not working after restart

Tags: bloomberg

And we have to kill it in task manager and restart the service manually every time..

Any thoughts why and how to fix it?

(Can't kill the process using a schedule task as it requires admin access)

Comment: Running the API Diagnostics and fixing any issues is generally enough. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes but still happens after restart